# Scene Kit Swift Node Multiple Rotation

Tags: swift, scenekit

In SceneKit with Swift, I can make only one rotation.

I want to rotate camera at the z-axis every time the user taps the screen.

```
func handleTap(){
    println("start")
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)

    SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock(){
        println("done")
    }

    _cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1, CFloat( -M_PI_4 ) * 0.5 )

    SCNTransaction.commit()

}
```

However, I want to keep rotating it with every touch. I think I need a `scnvector4` multiplier, but I couldn't find that method.

How can I multiply 2 `scnvector4`s or what's another way I can keep rotating z-axis ?

Answer (score 8):

I was getting some weird behavior when I was modifying   node.rotation directly multiple times,

Instead, what seems to be working more reliably is some code like:

```
let xAngle = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(degToRad(90), 1, 0, 0)
let yAngle = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(degToRad(180), 0, 1, 0)
let zAngle = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(degToRad(0), 0, 0, 1)

var rotationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4Mult(xAngle, yAngle), zAngle)

node.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotationMatrix, node.Transform)
```

...somewhat bulky, but it works.  Btw, degToRad would be something like:

```
func degToRad(deg: Float) {
    return deg / 180 * Float(M_PI)
}
```

Comment: For that last line I recommend: node.pivot = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotationMatrix, node.transform)

Answer (score 3):

If you only ever rotate that node with the same axis, just add the vectors component-wise:

```
let cur = _cameraNode.rotation
_cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(cur.x, cur.y, cur.z, cur.w - CGFloat(M_PI_4 * 0.5))
```

Or, use a nice Swift trick -- it's possible to use dot notation to directly mutate a member of a property, and Swift will do the right thing when calling the property setter/getter:

```
_cameraNode.rotation.w -= CGFloat(M_PI_4 * 0.5)
```

Comment: Hi @rickster, how would you approach this if you first rotate on X axis, and next rotate on  Y axis?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the angle every time and change that line to:

_cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1, _cameraNode.rotation.w + ( -M_PI_4 ) * 0.5 )